# How to install UWP apps on a Truenas SMB share

Tags: windows, server-message-block, truenas

Overview:

Is it possible to install a UWP app on truenas via a smb network share? I know the whole encryption thing and acl will cause issues, but is there either a way to spoof encryption/acl?

Configuration:

Server running truenas 12
Data shared with SMB
Client running Windows 11 (dont make fun of me)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this post; you would have to use either an iSCSI block share or a virtual disk file that is mounted on boot.